# Truncate text in input type = file

Tags: css

Is it possible to truncate text in input `type="file"`, I mean, when I select file if `filename` is too long it should be `truncated`. I tried to apply `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but nothing changes.

Comment: i have faced the same problem, so instead of displaying whole text in div, I displayed an alert(); thus you can also use similar technique to notify user about his selection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you specify a fixed `width` for the input, most browsers should truncate it themselves. If not, you can still use `text-overflow: ellipsis` but it won't make any difference until you use it with two additional properties and also with width:

```
input[type=file] {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to actually truncate it, or change the display?  You cannot actually set the value, because that is a security risk -- no browser allows that.  To change the display of the value, you could do what matewka suggests.  For more control over the appearance, you could also hide the input and replace it with a `<span>` containing the value in question, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/jrJm2/2/

Answer (score 1):

**How to truncate filename for input type file:**

If you have a container around your file input you can set it to `display: flex;` and it will truncate with ellipsis.

Try messing with the width in the example below and trying removing `display: flex;` to see the text overflow the container with no truncation.

```css
.file-input-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-input-container">
  <input type="file" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all major browsers, I don't think you can set what is in a file upload box, because that would open the door for you to trick or force users into uploading files to you that they shouldn't (not that you would, but other malicious people might).

Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve in a little more detail? It isn't clear to me why you would care about the length of the file name - aren't you really interested in the file's contents?